# How to replace value in .env file with awk?

Tags: regex, awk, environment-variables

I have a .env file containing the following:

```
{
    "Config" : {
        "host" : "XX.XXX.XX.XXX" ,
        "port" : 3019
    }
}
```

In a bash script I have an a variable `$myNewIP`. I want to replace the IP in the file with the value of my variable with an `awk` command.

I have tried

```
awk '/host/{sub(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})}1 .env
```

I am prompted that I have syntax errors. I thought this should work. What is wrong with the command?

Comment: awk doesn't support `\d`, use `[0-9]` instead.. use `\.` instead of `\\.` ... also, you haven't specified replacement string for `sub` and closing `'` is missing after `1` ...  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script wrt passing shell variables to awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a JSON-aware tool like `jq` to manipulate JSON files, not `awk`, `sed`, etc:

```
jq --arg myNewIP "$myNewIP" '.Config.host = $myNewIP' .env
{
  "Config": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 3019
  }
}
```